# Entity Framework trying to create unnecessary column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

When I create new migration, EF is trying to create an unnecessary column `ProductDataId`.

My models looks like this:

```
public abstract class ObjectBaseData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}

[Table("Products")]
public class ProductData : ObjectBaseData
{
     public List<CategoryProductData> CategoriesIds { get; set; } = new List<CategoryProductData>();
    // ...
}

[Table("Categories")]
public class CategoryData : ObjectBaseData
{
}

[Table("CategoryProduct")]
public class CategoryProductData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryData))]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductData))]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProductData> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryData> Categories { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

When I create new migration, I get this in the migration script:

```
public partial class MyMigration : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "ProductDataId",
            table: "CategoryProduct",
            type: "int",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_CategoryProduct_ProductDataId",
            table: "CategoryProduct",
            column: "ProductDataId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_CategoryProduct_Products_ProductDataId",
            table: "CategoryProduct",
            column: "ProductDataId",
            principalTable: "Products",
            principalColumn: "Id");

        // ...
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This nonsensical column began to be created when I renamed some classes (nothing changed, only renamed).

I tried to enter the exact name in the `ForeignKey` attribute which I defined in `Table` attribute but it doesn't help...

```
[Table("CategoryProduct")]
public class CategoryProductData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryData))]    ---> [ForeignKey("Categories")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductData))]     ---> [ForeignKey("Products")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

What is the reason why this started happening? And how could I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This nonsensical column began to be created when I renamed some classes (nothing changed, only renamed)

Well, this is enough to break the EFC naming conventions, which for [foreign key properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions#discovering-foreign-key-properties) are

> - `<navigation property name><principal key property name>`
> - `<navigation property name>Id`
> - `<principal entity type name><principal key property name>`
> - `<principal entity type name>Id`

Note the terms *property* and *entity* (class) because these are not the same as column and table names which are configured separately.

As you can see, with your latest naming, `ProductId` does not match any of the aforementioned patterns. You have no navigation property, so the first two do not apply, and the last two resolve to `ProductDataId`. As a result, EF Core treats your `ProductId` property like a regular property/column, and creates the necessary FK property/column `ProductDataId` using a [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#foreign-key-shadow-properties).

> I tried to enter the exact name in the ForeignKey attribute which I defined in Table attribute but it doesn't help...

`ForeignKey` is a confusing attribute, which I would recommend to avoid, since it has different meanings depending on the place where it is applied. For instance, when applied to a reference navigation property, it specifies the FK *property* name. When applied to a FK *property*, it specifies the reference navigation *property* name. And when applied to a collection navigation property, nobody knows what it specifies. But in all the cases, the key word is *property* name (and not column, entity or table name).

The only reliable way to me is fluent API configuration, where you configure all the aspects of the relationship using C# compile time support. In this particular case, override `OnModelCreating` and add something like

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductData>()
    .HasMany(e => e.CategoriesIds) // collection nav property
    .WithOne() // no reference nav property
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId);
```

Btw, the `ProductData.CategoryId` also has the same issue, so better add similar configuration for it (and any similar). It won't hurt if they match EFC naming conventions, but will help if you later rename classes as you did.